# Using Selenium ITakeScreenshot returns Black Screen from IE Window?

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, webdriver, screenshot

i have a Class Library.dll with some SpecFlow tests written in C# / Selenium, when i am using the standard code to capture the screenshot with selenium class the file is just black window ?!

i have ran previous built solutions & .dll that uses the same driver versions (Selenium.IE32) and Browser Versions and it is capturing the screen fine... i am using the following code.

```
   ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(ScreenName, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
```

I have considered using the Rectangle/Bitmap to capture the entire screen but this seems to be within the System.Windows.Forms Namespace so i cannot use this in assembly type ClassLibrary.

any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the code used to initialize the web driver object? Maybe that will help identify the problem. The code you posted to capture the screenshot appears fine to me, so the problem must reside elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took out

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(StartURL);
```

And replaced with

```
options.InitialBrowserUrl = StartURL;
```

This is now capturing valid screenshots!

Comment: {      var options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
                        options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
                        options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
                        options.RequireWindowFocus = true;
                        options.InitialBrowserUrl = StartURL;
                        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options);
                        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
                        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. You could mark it as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

How do you launch your IE with selenium webdriver? What version of IE webdriver are you using? I use the recommended version of IEDriver in [this page](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) and use the following code. It can work well to me:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;

namespace ecwebdriver
{
    public class webdriver
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver;
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"D:\webdriver"); //here you should change to your webdriver path
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.bing.com");
            ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(@"D:\image\test.png");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yu Zhou, i did try this but was the same! - it seems removing the .GoToUrl for setting the initial browser as an IEOPTIONS Argument worked for me.